# How to expand a numeric string into full-range numbers by bash shell?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a numeric string input like

```
1-5 11 39-45
```

and would like to expand by Bash (or sed, awk, grep) as output,

```
1 2 3 4 5 11 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
```

P.S. It is better that I keep the input as it is, so I could not simply control the input as replacing 1-5 with {1..5}

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. On SO its highly encouraged for users(OP) to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so please do add the same in your question.

Comment: @TomFenech Very smart idea! I could further replace 1-5 with {1..5}

Comment: That's what I meant, my syntax was incorrect in my previous comment. You could change it to `{1..5} 11 {39..45}` as you said.

Comment: @TomFenech Actually, it is better I keep the input rather than control it. So just suppose I do not have control over the input format.

Comment: Please add your attempts to solve the problem yourself, state whether that "numeric string" is being passed to a script as a parameter, multiple parameters, coming from a pipe, being read from a file, or something else, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue:

```
$ echo 1-5 11 39-45 | perl -pe 's/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/join " ", $1 .. $2/ge'
1 2 3 4 5 11 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line, and prints each line after running the code on it
- `s///` is the substitution operator. Here, it matches two numbers separated by a dash, and replaces them by the expanded list.
- The `/g` means all occurrences will be replaced, not just the first one.
- The `/e` tells `s///` to interpret the replacement part as code.
- `$1` and `$2` contain what the first and second pair of parentheses matched, i.e. the numbers.
- `..` is the range operator.
- [join](http://p3rl.org/join) joins a list into a string.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/{\1..\2}/g;s/.*/bash -c "echo &"/e' file
```

Convert hyphenated numbers into brace expansion expressions and then evaluate the pattern space as a bash echoed line.

N.B. If `/bin/sh` points to bash already then just use:

```
 sed -E 's/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/{\1..\2}/g;s/.*/echo &/e' file
```

If the input is a variable use:

```
v='1-5 11 39-45'
<<<"$v" sed -E 's/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/{\1..\2}/g;s/.*/bash -c "echo &"/e'
```